# Error displaying image from SQLite3

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, sqlite, blob

I am saving images from my application as BLOB in SQLite3. When I retrieve, I want to display it in the app, but I keep getting 'mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar'. I can't seem to find a sample code that allows you to retrieve an image and display it (other than on a webpage).

I believe the problem is converting from blob to a numpy array, but I can't find information on how to do that.

I'm posting the short test program with all three defs, but the one I am speaking about is the readImageFromDB

```
import cv2
import sqlite3

def readImage():

    newimage=cv2.imread('_testImage.jpg',-1) #read as is

    insertImageIntoDB(newimage)


def insertImageIntoDB(newimage):
    db = sqlite3.connect('testImages.dat')
    db.execute('''INSERT INTO images(image) VALUES(?)''', (newimage, ))    
    db.commit()
    db.close()

def readImageFromDB():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("testImages.dat")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM images")
    row=cur.fetchone()
    conn.close()

    img = row[1]

    #display on screen
    cv2.imshow('testimg', img)
    k=cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF #escape key

    if k == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows() #close windows

    elif k==ord('s'): #save image
        cv2.imwrite('testImage.png', img)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows() #close windows


def createTestImageDatabase():
    # Creates a non-conformance database
    ncdb = sqlite3.connect('testImages.dat')
    ncdb.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, image BLOB)")
    ncdb.commit()
    ncdb.close()

#createTestImageDatabase()
#readImage()
readImageFromDB()
```

Comment: please try to convert blob to numpy array and then use cv2.imgshow

Comment: That's the information that seems to be lacking on this site and on the web. I found very few examples, and each example gives me an error:
ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size

What I have used so far is:
numpy.frombuffer(image, dtype=numpy.float32)
and
img = numpy.fromstring(image)